# Trying to login users by checking if they exist in list. C#

Tags: c#, authentication

I'm trying to login a user by checking if the user exists in a list. I'm having trouble accessing the list and it's objects. Here is my code. Any help or hints at a solution are greatly appreciated

Thanks

```
public class User 
{
    public string userName;
    public string password;
    public string address;
    public int contactNumber;
}

public class UserController 
{
    public List<User> userList;

    public UserController() 
    {
        userList = new List<User>();
    }

    public void RegisterUser(string username, string pass, string add, int contact) 
    {
        User newUser = new User();
        newUser.userName = username;
        newUser.password = pass;
        newUser.address = add;
        newUser.contactNumber = contact;
        userList.Add(newUser);

        Console.WriteLine(newUser.userName);
        Console.WriteLine(userList);
    }

    public void LoginUser(string username, string pass) 
    {
        User checkUser = new User();
        int idx = checkUser.userName.IndexOf(username);

        if (userList[idx].password == pass) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Login successful"); 
            string[] loggedInUser = {username, pass};              
        } 
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect password");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're instantiating a new User and checking its username property to see if it contains the username:

```
User checkUser = new User();
int idx = checkUser.userName.IndexOf(username);
```

Instead you want to check your list of users:

```
RegisterUser("Jeremy","Thompson","",1);  
User user = userList.FirstOrDefault(u => u.userName == username);  
if (user != null) {
   if (user.password == password) {
```